# Is it possible to draw a KineticJS shape directly on canvas context?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am writing a small game using the Jaws framework. I would like to use KineticJS to draw some shapes on my canvas context. Is it possible to draw the shapes directly on a context without creating a Stage and a Layer first?
Something like

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({...params...);
circle.draw(myContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe each KineticJS object has drawFunc as its property. If you can take that one out and apply to canvas directly, you won't need stage or layer,I guess.

Trying ...

Hmm .. no. drawFunc is using object dependent properties. i.e. this.getRadius().

However, you still can see how it is drawn by printing out the drawFunc

```
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
<script>
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 250,y: 250, radius: 70,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});

console.log(circle.drawFunc);
</script>
```

Here is the output of that console.log command.

```
function (canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, this.getRadius(), 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    canvas.fillStroke(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to work with canvas and canvas context directly but I thought I could save me some time implementing the drawing of all those shapes by using kinetic.